# Typescript does not enforce void return type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, void

Seems like Typescript does not enforce `void` return types.
Take a look at the following:

```js
type Noop = () => void

const f: Noop = () => 1
const g: Noop = () => []
const h: Noop = () => () => 1

const u: void = undefined
const x: void = 1

type NoopUndef = () => undefined
const fn: NoopUndef = () => 1
```

You can also find it on [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=27&pln=2&pc=1#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAOQPZKnAvHAFASgwPjgDckBLAE1FAGMkA7AZzDgDMAuRFNTXAuARhr0mcAOYdkqDNjzpCAbQC6QxswAWErtN5yZfQSBUiArhxIVpxuuRgtSdGJRC1VcAB5my5aQdCRYcACCAEYMxgBO3jyyhFY2dg5OLiIs7EGhEVF6uvxAA)

TS correctly reports that assigning `1` to `x` is a type error however, all the `Noop` functions pass the typecheck. I would expect TS to complain when returning a value for a `void` return type. It works correctly on the `undefined` version `NoopUndef`.

Can anyone explain why this behaviour occurs and what I can do to enforce the type error?

Comment: A function typed as `void` pretty much means that the caller of that function can't *expect* a return value, meaning the caller should ignore any and all return values. Then it doesn't matter whether the function returns anything.

Comment: But I can see many reasons why this would cause issues.
For example, you're mapping an array, and on some condition, you run a function that returns `void`. You'd expect the mapped array to contain `void`s, which was you say, should be discarded. So you then try to filter them out, but since the function actually returned values instead, they don't get filtered out. 
It would be much better to strictly enforce the absence of the returned value.

Comment: If you're mapping a `void` function, you're doing it wrong to begin with. Use `forEach` in that case.

Comment: That is not the point, and does not answer the question. 
Besides, my example mentioned a situation where some elements are mapped, but where also an effect happens and as such we get `void` as well. The non enforcement of the return type means a bug could sneak in.

Comment: Or take a different example, using a lib you have no control over. They expose a function that takes an argument of type: `() => void | Function`.
You want to be explicit about the 2 kinds of callback, so you try to type it as:
`type Simple = () => void` &
`type WithAction = () => Function`.
This would still allow the consumer to attempt to write a `Simple` implementation but return a `Function`, which would result in a different behaviour

EDIT: styling and typos

Comment: Well, this is all explicitly documented: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void

Comment: Fair enough, I was unaware that it was desired behaviour, although I disagree it with. 
If you'd like to make a proper Answer pointing to the docs and explaining it's desired behaviour and that it is not possible to extract a type that enforces a void return, I'll gladly accept it